# How can I create regex to match this example?

Tags: regex

I am trying to create regex to match the all of the date, description and amount.  I almost have it BUT the last line is messing up and matching on 30.98 instead of -58.00.

How can I match "06/14/18", "HECK ORDER00172 DES:FEE ID:1FCG0340 PMT INFO: PRODUCT(S): 30.98 S&H: 22.91 GA TAX: 4.11", "-58.00"? Along with all the other transaction lines?

Here is the expression I came up with '/([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})\s+(.*?)\s+([0-9\,-]+.[0-9]{2})/mis'

See this example here https://regex101.com/r/uuHcFT/1

```
06/13/18 CHECKCARD 0612 WAFFLE HOUSE 1554 BUFORD GA 163206888100637 CKCD
5812 XXXXXXXXXXXX7127 XXXX XXXX XXXX 7127
-14.00
06/13/18 CHECKCARD 0612 SQU*SQ *BRAVO MEX Buford GA 550191566794 CKCD
5812 XXXXXXXXXXXX7127 XXXX XXXX XXXX 7127
-12.56    
Date Check # Amount Date Check # Amount
06/05/18 1293 -1,289.00 06/14/18 1309 -500.72
Date Transaction description Amount
06/01/18 FEE  -29.95
06/14/18 CHECK ORDER00172 DES:FEE ID:1FCG0340
PMT INFO: PRODUCT(S): 30.98 S&H: 22.91 GA TAX: 4.11
-58.00
Total service fees -$87.95
```

I want the expression to match the following:

```
1) "06/13/18", "CHECKCARD 0612 WAFFLE HOUSE 1554 BUFORD GA 163206888100637 CKCD 5812 XXXXXXXXXXXX7127 XXXX XXXX XXXX 7127", "-14.00"
2) "06/13/18", "CHECKCARD 0612 SQU*SQ *BRAVO MEX Buford GA 550191566794 CKCD 5812 XXXXXXXXXXXX7127 XXXX XXXX XXXX 7127", "-12.56"
3) "06/05/18", "1293", "-1,289.00"
4) "06/14/18", "1309", "-500.72"
5) "06/01/18", "FEE", "-29.95"
6) "06/14/18", "CHECK ORDER00172 DES:FEE ID:1FCG0340 PMT INFO: PRODUCT(S): 30.98 S&H: 22.91 GA TAX: 4.11", "-58.00"
```

Comment: Your regex looks like it already working.  What is the problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to match "-58.00" not "30.98" on this "06/14/18 CHECK ORDER00172 DES:FEE ID:1FCG0340
PMT INFO: PRODUCT(S): 30.98 S&H: 22.91 GA TAX: 4.11
-58.00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to require the final group to be either:

(1) immediately followed by a date

(2) at the end of a line, and have negative lookahead for the first characters of the next line to be digits/decimals only

Also note that instead of `[0-9]` you can just use `\d`:

https://regex101.com/r/uuHcFT/3

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\s+(.*?)\s+([0-9\,\-]+\.\d{2}) *(?=\d\d\/|$(?!\n-?[\d\.]+$))
                                                   ^ ---->
```

Comment: Thank you! this works for that line but breaks 

"06/05/18 1293 -1,289.00 06/14/18 1309 -500.72"

This should be two separate matches, but matches as one

Comment: See edit, you can allow lookahead for a date as well

Comment: this is perfect.  for some reason I cannot wrap my head around the lookaheads